# How to align the icon left and text middle in a Raised button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a button with an icon and a text where both of them aligned in the middle,i want the icon to be in the left and the text of the button to be in the middle. can someone look into it and help me with how to do it.

Here's My code:

```
Widget _signInButton() {


return ButtonTheme(
  height: 30,

 minWidth: 250,

  child: RaisedButton(
    color: Colors.white,

    splashColor: Colors.grey,
    onPressed: () {
      signInWithGoogle().whenComplete(() {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) {
              return FirstScreen();
            },
          ),
        );
      });
    },
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
    highlightElevation: 0,
   // borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image(image: AssetImage("Assets/google_logo.png"), height: 35.0),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
              child: Text(
                'Sign in with Google',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15,
                  color: Colors.black87,
```

Comment: Try removing the `Flexible` widget wrapping image.

Comment: When i Remove the Flexible widget, button iss covering both the sides completely and im not able to reduce the width

Comment: Kindly check what i have done

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `Expanded flex 1` for image, `Expanded flex 2` for text

code snippet

```
Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Image(
          image: AssetImage("Assets/google_logo.png"),
          height: 35.0),
                    ),
Expanded(
     flex: 2,
        child: Padding(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _signInButton(),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _signInButton() {
  return ButtonTheme(
      height: 30,
      minWidth: 250,
      child: RaisedButton(
          color: Colors.white,
          splashColor: Colors.grey,
          onPressed: () {
            /*signInWithGoogle().whenComplete(() {
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return FirstScreen();
          },
        ),
      );
    });*/
          },
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
          highlightElevation: 0,
          // borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
              child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Image(
                          image: AssetImage("Assets/google_logo.png"),
                          height: 35.0),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                            child: Text('Sign in with Google',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15, color: Colors.black87))))
                  ]))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the same situation. I tried this way and it worked for me.
Inside your button child widget paste the `Row` widget portion.
Here is the code:

```
Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
         ....
     Row(
         children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () { //do whatever you want},
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.clear,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Text(
                  'Your Button Text',
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
    )
```